# Green's function for a charge in front of a conductive sphere

Tags: electrostatics, conductors, greens-functions

For simplicity let's assume that the conductive sphere of radius R is in the center of the Cartesian reference frame. The Greens function is of the form:

$$G(\vec r, \vec r')= \frac 1 {4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac 1 {|\vec r - \vec r'|} + F(\vec r, \vec r')$$

And in the surface of the the conductive sphere it must become zero, therefore:

$$F(\vec r, \vec r')= \frac A {4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac 1 {|\vec r - \vec r_m'(\vec r')|}$$

Notation:

$\vec r$ is an arbitrary position in space where we want to find the value of the green function.

$\vec r'$ is the position vector from the origin to where the charge distribution, which generates the electric field is.

$\vec r_m'(\vec r')$ is the position vector of the mirror charge inside the conductive sphere. This mirror charge is in the same radial path that the real charge outside the sphere is. And they are related as $\vec r_m'=\alpha \vec r$, $\alpha $ is just a constant.

As I said $G(\vec r,\vec r')|_{\vec r = \vec R}=0$.

This means:

$$\frac 1 {4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac 1 {|\vec R - \vec r'|} + \frac A {4\pi \epsilon_0} \frac 1 {|\vec R - \vec r_m'(\vec r')|}=0$$.

This expression is equal to:

$$\frac 1 {\sqrt{R^2 + r'^2 - 2 \cdot R \cdot r' \cos \gamma}} + \frac A {\sqrt{R^2 + r_m'^2 - 2 \cdot R \cdot r_m' \cos \gamma}}$$, where $\gamma$ is the angle between R and $r'$ and  $r_m'$.

This is what I don't understand, how does the vector difference becomes a quadratic expression?

Comment: The denominators are the magnitude of vector differences.

Comment: yes and? that denominator can be written as $\sqrt{(x_R - x')^2 + (y_R - y')^2 + (z_R - z')^2}$ translate to the quadratic expression ?

Comment: Are you familiar with cosine laws? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: I was just googling about this xD. Basically is the case of finding the side of an triangle when you know 2 and the angle between them, right?

Comment: ⬆️ Yeah, correct!